# Javascript return using colon

Tags: javascript

When you see code like this:

```
var spa = (function () {
..
..


  return { initModule: initModule };
}());
```

Can someone explain the line `return { initModule: initModule }` ?

Comment: [It's a revealing module pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) (well, almost - your syntax is slightly wrong). You define the module in the function (including all 'private' methods and variables) and then return an object containing only those methods you want in the API. In this case there's only one method: `spa.initModule()`.

Comment: What you've pasted is an IIFE, which returns an object and a few extra ")" and "}".

Comment: It returns initModule function

Comment: What is the purpose of writing initModule twice?

Comment: One is the key, the other is the value.

Comment: If you didn't recognize [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers) in the return value, you should start to learn some basics of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a revealing module pattern. See the following syntax.

```
var spa = (function () {
..
..
  function initModule () {
      // Your code
   }

  function otherModule () {
      // Your code
   }

  return { initModule: initModule };
}());
```

Every variable function defined inside `spa` object will not be directly accessible.
In module pattern if we return `spa` as a whole object, then we've to define which function/ variables will be returned.

So, our code for `initModule` will be

```
spa.initModule = function () {};
```

In revealing module pattern, we just return a single object which contains all the variables and functions available to user using `spa` object.

The `return { initModule: initModule }` line actually tells the `spa` object's function called `initModule` (defined 2nd time) is available outside this module. The first time `initModule` is called is the name by which it can be accessed.

This is equivalent to `return { test: initModule }`. Now you've to call `spa.test()` to execute `initModule` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

[It's a revealing module pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) (well, almost - your syntax is slightly wrong). You define the module in the function (including all 'private' methods and variables) and then return an object containing only those methods you want in the API. In this case there's only one method: spa.initModule().

It should look like:

```
var spa = (function () {

  function initModule() {
    //do something
  }

  return { initModule: initModule };

}());
```

`spa` is actually an object, not a function. The function is only returning the module API to `spa`. So you define `initModule` in the function but to return it you need to add it as a value in an object. Assuming you want the same method name on `spa` you use the key name `initModule` too.

You can see in the demo that in the second example I've used `hallo` as the object key name.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0k9hs6y9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**First**

`(function () {})();` is anoynomous function and will be executed when script is processed

`{}` is object literel in javascript

**Overall**

spa will contain an object reference to `{ initModule: initModule }`

`spa.intiModule` will return its value whatever is set. if `initModule` is function reference then it will return reference to function and you have to call `spa.intiModule()` to execute it